# Replace menu toggle button on mobile with all items of menu in wordpress blog

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have my wordpress blog www.technikes.com .

you can see that all items are displayed on menu on desktop/laptop,But when I open the same blog on mobile then all menu items are replace by toggle menu button(three lines) as you can see here
[blog on mobile with main menu three line button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40YwL.png)

what i am trying is all my items of menu (java,android,technology,about,contact) should be displayed in mobile as it is displaying in desktop.I donot want three line main menu button in mobile.

**what I already tried:-**

- I installed plugins like "responsive menu" and "Max Mega Menu" and "Menu Items Visibility Control" on wordpress dashboard.
- I try to change my "media screen and (min width 600px)" section under style.css of my theme.
- I try to change breakpoint at which menu start appearing(by default it is 600px). 
  None of them work.

please suggest some solution.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a backup before you change anything.

Open `style.css`

On line number 900, Change

```
#main-nav-button, #top-nav-button {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

to

```
#main-nav-button, #top-nav-button {
    display: none; // it will hide the button coming on mobile.
}
```

On line 655

Change

```
.main-navigation {
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
.main-navigation {
    display: block; // this will display the desktop navigation
}
```

Also on line 687

Change

```
.main-navigation ul, .top-navigation ul {
    display: none;
}
```

to

```
.main-navigation ul, .top-navigation ul {
    display: block;
}
```

And your end result will be(please check image)

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQqf3.jpg)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It solve my problem but still i have on e doubt that search icon is overlapping on one of my menu item.Also as it is taking three lines to cover all menu items so is it any way to reduce it to 2 lines.Thanks

Comment: Glad to help. For bringing search icon to next line remove position absolute for .awaken-search-button-icon on style.css 812. But that might effect desktop version also. So, please add it in a media query. And if your problem is resolved. then please check this answer as the right answer. Have a great day

Comment: Are there any plugins available that reduce space between menu items for mobile only?

Comment: No. It is just a few lines of CSS customization. If you are not comfortable with CSS then ask any of your friend developer. May be then can help